# Valid circumstances where P(A) = P(A|B)⋅P(B)

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

Normally we would say that:

$$\ P(A\cap B) = P(A|B)⋅P(B)  =  P(B|A)⋅P(A)
$$

but I am wondering if there are any valid circumstances where this would hold true:

$$\ P(A) = P(A|B)⋅P(B) $$

I was thinking that if `B` was the *only* thing that caused `A`, that this *would* be true. I swear I saw this in a textbook somewhere but now I can't find it.

Comment: This will hold if $A \subseteq B$.  Prove it, using the definition of $P(A | B)$.

Comment: Not sure I follow, mind providing a full answer?

Comment: I guess it's because if ⊆, then `P(A and B)`  = `P(A)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to formalize your answer in the comments a little better:

If $A\subseteq B$ then $A\cap B$=$A$ and therefore $\text{Pr}(A\cap B)=\text{Pr}(A)$.